Unity C# script not working i used a bool function to disable / enable my movement script
The input escape key cancel function works but the bool function I added to determine if the key is being pressed twice to enable / disable player movement for my menu ui. does not.
Any ideas?
Does anyone have any idea why this doesn't work?
If I remove the second bool "not moving", it works, but with both of them in the script nothing happens when I press the escape key.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class menu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool IsMoving;
    public bool NotMoving;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        IsMoving = true;
        NotMoving = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Cancel"))
        {
            if (IsMoving)
            {
                GetComponent<SC_FPSController>().enabled = false;
                NotMoving = true;
                IsMoving = false;
            }

            if (NotMoving)
            {
                GetComponent<SC_FPSController>().enabled = true;
                IsMoving = true;
                NotMoving = false;
            }
        }
    }
}


else if(NotMoving) otherwise it toggles on and then toggles off immediately. Having two flags for the same thing is overkill. Pick one, like isMoving. If it is true they are moving, if it is false they are not.

Retired Ninja's comment answered the question for me.
else if fixes the issue instead of if on the second function.
